# How to called OneToOneFields without generating a pylint no-menber (E1101 )

Tags: django, foreign-keys, pylint

I am working with django and, I am in trouble to called a OneToOneFields without generation a pylint.

here is my code

```py
class A(models.Model):
    attr_1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(A, models.CASCADE, null=False)
    other_attr = models.BooleanField(default=False)

my_object = A.objects.first()
print(my_object.b.other_attr)
```

When I run my pylint, it generates a E1101 (no-member) on this line.

As I do not want to make another called to the DB, I do not want to write something like this

```py
my_b_object = B.objects.get(a=my_object)
```

Does someone as an idea on how to solve that?

PS: the goal is to no put neither a

```py
# pylint: disable=E1101
```

at the end on my line :-)

thanks by advance!!!

django version -> 1.11.20

pylint version -> 2.3.1

Comment: Have you installed [pylint-django](https://pypi.org/project/pylint-django/)?

Comment: Yes, I have the version 2.0.6

Comment: This is unfortunately an [open issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django/issues/188) with `pylint-django`. Disabling `E1101` may be the only alternative for now, unless you want to try using `Flake8` instead.

Comment: Good to know, I will follow this issue. I am working in a production environment where pylint needs to run. I will disabled pylint on the line so. Thanks for you explanation!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I will disable this pylint issue on my code, and follow [the issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django/issues/188) mentionned by [@evergreen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6067149/evergreen).

I will now have

```py
class A(models.Model):
    attr_1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(A, models.CASCADE, null=False)
    other_attr = models.BooleanField(default=False)

my_object = A.objects.first()
print(my_object.b.other_attr)    # pylint: disable=E1101
```